# .NET Remoting with Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-remoting, activator

I need to dynamically load an interface assembly that I use on client-side remoting. Something like this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  TcpClientChannel clientChannel = new TcpClientChannel();
  ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(clientChannel, false);

  Assembly interfaceAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile("RemotingInterface.dll");
  Type iTheInterface = 
    interfaceAssembly.GetType("RemotingInterface.ITheService");

  RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownClientType(iTheInterface,
                                        "tcp://localhost:9090/Remotable.rem");
  object wellKnownObject = Activator.GetObject(iTheInterface, 
                                        "tcp://localhost:9090/Remotable.rem");
}
```

Only I can't seem to grasp how to call any methods as I can't cast the Activator.GetObject. How can I create a proxy of ITheService without knowing the interface at compile-time?

Comment: Have you considered using WCF instead of Remoting? Remoting has been deprecated in favor of WCF.

Comment: @John, I'm painfully aware that Remoting is deprecated. Unfortunately due to existing client code I can't switch to WCF without causing havoc to other peoples code. Some day...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got an answer from [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/ab0c3fda-a9b8-483e-9eb5-36ceabf35569).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  TcpClientChannel clientChannel = new TcpClientChannel();
  ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(clientChannel, false);

  Assembly interfaceAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile("RemotingInterface.dll");
  Type iTheInterface = interfaceAssembly.GetType("RemotingInterface.ITheService");

  RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownClientType(iTheInterface,
                                    "tcp://localhost:9090/Remotable.rem");
  object wellKnownObject = Activator.GetObject(iTheInterface, 
                                    "tcp://localhost:9090/Remotable.rem");

  MethodInfo m = iTheInterface.GetMethod("MethodName");
  m.Invoke(wellKnownObject, new object[] { "Argument"});
}
```

Comment: If you're going to be loading the Assembly into the current AppDomain, and you know the typename, why not add `RemotingInterface.dll` as a reference to the project, so you are able to cast like `ITheInterface wellKnownObject = (ITheInterface)Activator.GetObject(...);`, then execute the method directly? If you're looking to sandbox the dynamically loaded Assembly, this doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

The returned object implements the interface, so you can use reflection to get its member methods and invoke them.

Or, in C#4, you can use `dynamic`:

```
dynamic wellKnownObject = Activator.GetObject(iTheInterface, 
    "tcp://localhost:9090/Remotable.rem");

wellKnownObject.SomeMethod(etc ..);
```

Comment: Hi Ben. Thanks for the reply. The dynamic method call throws RuntimeBinderException 'System.MarshalByRefObject' does not contain a definition for 'SomeMethod'. Also, I know how to get the methods of the interface, but not how to get them from wellKnownObject.

Comment: `SomeMethod` was an example name of a method. Replace it with a method that you KNOW is in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

First, inspect the available methods/interfaces of your object:

```
object wellKnownObject =
  Activator.GetObject(iTheInterface, "tcp://localhost:9090/Remotable.rem");

var objType = wellKnownObject.GetType();
var methods = objType.GetMethods();
var interfaces = objType.GetInterfaces();
```

After you're sure about the method you want to invoke,

1. Consider using [DLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233052.aspx) and/or wrap the dynamic object in a DynamicObject container.
2. Use [`methods[i].Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke.aspx) on the object.

Here are some examples:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  using System;

  class Program
  {

    static void Main()
    {
      //Using reflection:
      object obj = GetUnknownObject();
      var objType = obj.GetType();

      var knownInterface = objType.GetInterface("IA");
      var method = knownInterface.GetMethod("Print");
      method.Invoke(obj, new object[] { "Using reflection" });

      //Using DRL
      dynamic dObj = GetUnknownObject();
      dObj.Print("Using DLR");

      //Using a wrapper, so you the dirty dynamic code stays outside
      Marshal marshal = new Marshal(GetUnknownObject());
      marshal.Print("Using a wrapper");

    }

    static object GetUnknownObject()
    {
      return new A();
    }
  } //class Program

  class Marshal
  {
    readonly dynamic unknownObject;
    public Marshal(object unknownObject)
    {
      this.unknownObject = unknownObject;
    }

    public void Print(string text)
    {
      unknownObject.Print(text);
    }
  }

  #region Unknown Types
  interface IA
  {
    void Print(string text);
  }

  class A : IA
  {
    public void Print(string text)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(text);
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
  #endregion Unknown Types
}
```

Comment: Could you please show an example of reflection? The object is of type MarshalByRefObject. I'm not quite sure how to map that to the interface.

Comment: @Shimmy, Thanks for the update. Unfortunately none of your examples work. Remember that I'm using dynamic assembly loading _and_ .NET Remoting. I don't even know the concrete class that the server is instantiating so I can't call `new A()`. I have to use `Activator.GetObject`, but the object I'm getting is of type `MarshalByRefObject` which doesn't implement any interfaces. If I call `objType.GetInterfaces` I get an empty array in return. If I do this the traditional way and statically reference the DLL, then I can call `IA knownInterface = (IA)Activator.GetObject(...)`.

Comment: @Rubio, **1)** In my example, the `new A()` is your `Activator.GetObject`, the common denominator is that the variable type will only be known at runtime when its set to the concrete value **2)** How can you be sure that the method you'er looking for exist in that remote class? **3)** Lemme ask you a question, did you checkout what's in iTheInterface using reflection or [TypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.aspx)?

Comment: @Shimmy, 1) Gotcha. 2) I can't. 3) Yes I did. In my sample code `knownInterface` would be null if I got it the way you did. However, if I get it the way I did in my original sample, it works. So technically your reflection method is correct, I just have to get the interface differently. I still can't get the DLR or wrapper methods to work.

Comment: I see. That's interesting. Thank you.
BTW, if your own answer answers the question, please mark it as answer.

Comment: Always thought it's kind of frowned upon to mark your own reply as answer ;-) BTW, any idea why the DLR methods don't work when the object is created through Activator.GetObject? I'm not too familiar with DLR.

Comment: Since SO is about helping people, you should mark as answered for the sake of the users you're going to help, and I'm not mentioning the reputation you might gain from. As per the DLR issue, maybe the method is not public? any other access or binding attributes etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Can I get the Interface information from the remoting URL like http://localhost:8080/xxx.rem?wsdl.

As WebService, I can get the interface information from the service url, http://xXX.xx.xxx.xx/url.svc?wsdl, and compile the assembly by myself code, and invoke methods via reflection.

Comment: This post is about .NET Remoting. Google 'dynamic WCF' if you're dealing with web services.